# Chart View Integration issue?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I implemented Chart view from [GitHub link Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)  help me how to set chart data from my api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after getting response from API i use this below lines of code to populate chart data

```
   var newData = [ChartDataEntry]()
   var month:[String] = []
   for i in 0 ..< self.graphJSON.count{

    if self.graphJSON[i]["savings"].null == nil{
       let saving = self.graphJSON[i]["savings"].rawString()!
        if let savingInt = Int("\(saving)"){
            newData.append(ChartDataEntry(x:Double(i),y:Double(savingInt)))
        }
     }

     if self.graphJSON[i]["month"].null == nil{
       month.append("\(self.graphJSON[i]["month"].rawString()!)")
     }
   }


chartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
chartView.rightAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = false

chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:month)

//Also, you probably want to add:
chartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
//Generate Colors
var circleColors: [NSUIColor] = []           // arrays with circle color definitions
for i in 0 ..< 12 {
    if i == 11 {
        let color = UIColor(red:0.84, green:0.31, blue:0.12, alpha:1.0)
        circleColors.append(color)
    }
    else{
        let color = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.67, blue:0.60, alpha:1.0)
        circleColors.append(color)
    }
}

let data = LineChartData()
let ds1 = LineChartDataSet(values: newData, label: "Savings in ₹")
ds1.colors = [NSUIColor.lightGray]
ds1.circleColors = circleColors
data.addDataSet(ds1)

let xAxis:XAxis = chartView.xAxis
xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

let leftAxis:YAxis = chartView.leftAxis
leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

let rightAxis:YAxis = chartView.rightAxis
rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false



self.chartView.data = data
self.chartView.data?.highlightEnabled = false
self.chartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor.white //give color you want here
self.chartView.chartDescription?.text = "Savings Graph"
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Okay Ganesh Manickam

Comment: it's working fine

Comment: welcome, If you consider that your problem is solved, you can accept answer, this will mark the question as answered. Cheers!

Comment: how can i set diffrent background color?

Comment: `self.chartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor.white` using this you can change colour

Comment: it's not woking

Comment: you need to change grid color or entire background color?

Comment: entire background color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160076/discussion-between-ganesh-manickam-and-ashu-designer).